# How to share large dataframes between two different Python scripts and versions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dask, arcticdb

I want to share data between several Python scripts running in different environments.
My data comes as Pandas Dataframes (and dask dataframes). Typically, the Dataframes contain floats, ints, strings, and pd.timestamps. Their size can be large (about 15,000,000 rows x 20 columns).

Unfortunately, the dependencies of my script environments are incompatible. Not only are the Pandas versions different (2.0, 1.2), but so are the Python versions (3.10 & 3.8).

Here is a brief summary of my programs scripts:

- Script A -> fetch & store:
  Fetches data from the internet and stores it using arcticdb.
- Script B -> ml prediction:
  Performs machine learning with the data from script A *and* stores the predictions in script A's store, so I don't have to make the ml predictions again
- Script C -> processing:
  Loads data from script A's store and requests new predictions from script B

A simple dataflow diagramm:

```
C <-┌-- B <---> A
    └---------- A
```

Due to the size of the Dataframes, I want to avoid writing anything to disk to share my data.

I've read about streaming pickled data, but since A and B need to communicate back and forth, this won't work since pickle is only downward (not upward) compatible.

Is there any way to avoid converting the Dataframes before and after sharing (for e.g. df -> dict -> *share* -> dict -> df) to reduce overhead?

Comment: Given the incompatible `dependencies` and the need to share data between different Python scripts running in different environments, you can consider using a `message queue system` like RabbitMQ or Apache Kafka.

Comment: or the message queue ZeroMQ

Comment: The general pickle file format version can be explicitly set to ensure it is the same. The main problem may be the pandas version where one version may not be able to unpickle data from the other version. If you know that only these specific versions are used you could just try it out and use it if it works.

Comment: You need to use dask for this? I am here because of the tag on the question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggetions I will look into it.
@mdurant Since I have dask dataframes, too I thought there might be a way using dask to solve my problem. Thats why I tagged it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the dask point of view, (distributed) clusters are multi-tenant, so you can totally connect from one client and create a dataset for another client to use ( https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/publish.htm ).

However, you normally wish and require matched versions. If the client dask/distributed version does not match the scheduler and workers, things may or may not work at all (expect warnings at least). *IF* you use the dask.dataframe API in the client, this is a problem as pickling would be the way data is copied between workers.

However, you can run plain functions on workers, invoked from the client, even to create dataframes and "publish" them.

```
def make_it():
    from distributed import get_client
    import dask.dataframe as dd
    client = get_client()
    df = ...
    df2 = client.persist(df)
    client.publish_dataset(negative_accounts=df2)

client = dask.distributed.Client(<cluster address>)
client.submit(make_it)
```

With this approach, the first client is using the versions of pandas on the workers and not pickling anything except the function code, so this very likely might work. If the second client session does have matched versions, it can client.get_dataset without problem.

Comment: This sounds interesting I will test that. The best thing is that I don't have to install and learn new packages (except for dask-distributed).